# Mysql complicated select

Tags: mysql, select

Мне необходимо найти все посты (из таблицы `posts`) у которых отношение количества лайков (`likes`) к подписчикам из таблицы пользователей (`users.subscribers`) больше определенной величины. Как это можно сделать одним запросом.

Я пробовал такой вариант:

```
 SELECT `userid`,`likes`
   FROM `posts`
  WHERE `likes` / (SELECT `subscribers` FROM `users` WHERE `user` = `userid`) > 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.userid, P.likes
  FROM posts P
  JOIN users U ON U.user=P.userid and P.likes/U.subscribers > 2
```

Comment: @alexanderbarakin В вопросе есть все таки некоторая неоднозначность, что именно имеется ввиду под `count` и я опасаюсь его трогать. Думаю стоит подождать, вдруг ТС появится и разъяснит этот момент и заодно переведет

Comment: Я поправил пример для ясности. Нужно найти все посты, у которых отношение лайков к подписчикам человека, который опубликовал запись, больше определенного значения, к примеру 2.

Comment: @SergeyVinitsky Тогда даже проще ... И придется похоже самому переводить ваш вопрос на русский, удалят ведь, он же на английском нарушает правила сайта